# Store all users information in a in custom class which are currently in room, i'm using smartfoxServer

Tags: android, unityscript, unity-game-engine, smartfoxserver

i'm using custom class to store user specific information class is as under:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class RoomPlayerInfo  {

private int minutes;
private int seconds;
private int miliSecond;
private string userName;

public int Minutes{
    get{ return minutes; }
    set{ minutes = value;}
}

public int Seconds{
    get{ return seconds; }
    set{ seconds = value; }
}

public string UserName{
    get{ return userName; }
    set{ userName = value; }
}

public int MiliSecond{
    get{ return miliSecond;}
    set{ miliSecond = value;}
}
}
```

i'm adding user at runtime in a list:

```
 private List<RoomPlayerInfo> listRoomPlayerInfo = new List<RoomPlayerInfo> ();

    RoomPlayerInfo rPI = new RoomPlayerInfo ();
    rPI.Minutes = diff.Minutes;
    rPI.Seconds = diff.Seconds;
    rPI.MiliSecond = diff.Milliseconds;
    rPI.UserName = sfs.MySelf.Name; 
    listRoomPlayerInfo.Add (rPI);
```

When i'm going to remove a player at runtime, it only remove the currentPlayer on each device, mean on each device remove the own player of such device, but i'm going to remove the player which take max time in game..
How i can done my job ???

```
void RemovePlayer()
{
    int i = 0;
    int removePlayerIndex = 0;
    if (listRoomPlayerInfo != null) {
        string playerID = listRoomPlayerInfo [i].UserName;

        for (; i < listRoomPlayerInfo.Count -1; i++) {
            if (listRoomPlayerInfo [i + 1].Minutes >= listRoomPlayerInfo [i].Minutes && listRoomPlayerInfo [i + 1].Seconds > listRoomPlayerInfo [i].Seconds && listRoomPlayerInfo[i+1].MiliSecond > listRoomPlayerInfo[i].MiliSecond) {
                playerID = listRoomPlayerInfo [i + 1].UserName;
                removePlayerIndex = i + 1;
            }
        }

        removeUserName.text = playerID + " Remove from room...";
        listRoomPlayerInfo.Remove (listRoomPlayerInfo [removePlayerIndex]);
    }
}
```

Comment: i didn't quite understand what you want to do..do you want RemovePlayer() to clear all the list? Also do you have an error? if yes can you please share it

Comment: only remove single player, not all the list,

Comment: ok so do you get an error?

Comment: yes,  on each device it can remove own player of device, but i want to remove player which contains max minutes, seconds or miliSeconds